# Referencing light DOM within web component

Tags: javascript, dom, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element

I'm using skate.js and trying to reference a web component's light DOM for validation and manipulation. The component looks like this:

```
<res-checkbox>
  <label slot="label">This is res-checkbox</label>
  <input slot="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="test-id" />
</res-checkbox>
```

I'm trying to reference the checkbox to validate that the it's there and add an id to it so the shadow DOM label can use reference it with the `for` attribute. However, I cannot figure out how to reference it after the component has been rendered.

```
import { Component, h, define, prop } from 'skatejs';

export class ResComponent extends Component {

  static get is() { return 'res-checkbox'; }

  renderedCallback() {
    console.log(this.querySelector('input[type="checkbox]'));
    // -> null
    console.log(this.getElementsByTagName('input')[0]);
    // -> undefined
    console.log(this.shadowRoot.querySelector('input[type="checkbox]'));
    // -> null
    console.log(this.shadowRoot.getElementById('checkbox').querySelector('input'));
    // -> null
    console.log(this.shadowRoot.getElementById('checkbox').assignedNodes());
    // -> []
    console.log(this.childNodes[1]);
    // -> undefined
    console.log(this.children[1]);
    // -> undefined
  }

  renderCallback() {
    return <div id="wrap">
      <slot name="label" id="label"></slot>
      <label id="fakeCheckbox">
        <slot name="checkbox" id="checkbox"></slot>
      </label>
    </div>;
  }

}

define(ResComponent);
```

What's the best way to reference light DOM in web components?

Answer (score 2):

Since the light DOM is just the normal DOM, you can reference elements inside it as usual :

```
var input = this.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]'))
var label = this.getElementsByTagName('label')[0]
```

If your example doesn't work, maybe it's because the method `renderedCallback()` is not called the right way, or at the right time.

Below is a running example in "vanilla" javascript (sorry I don't knwow SkateJS)

```js
customElements.define('res-checkbox', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })
      .innerHTML = `<div id="wrap">
        <slot name="label" id="label"></slot>
        <label id="fakeCheckbox">
          <slot name="checkbox" id="checkbox"></slot>
        </label>
      </div>`
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    var input = this.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]')
    var label = this.querySelector('label')
    console.log(input, label)
    label.setAttribute('for', input.id)
  }
})
```

```html
<res-checkbox>
  <label slot="label">This is res-checkbox</label>
  <input slot="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="test-id">
</res-checkbox>
```

Comment: Yep. That definitely works. I'll open an issue on the skate.js repo and see if I can get some guidance from them. Thanks!